# Prove that for any connected graph, there exists a closed walk that visits every edge exactly twice.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For this to occur, every vertex has to have an even degree. Since this is a connected graph, we know that this must be true.

How do you prove that the closed walk visits every edge *exactly twice*? Does the existences of a closed walk mean that there is a cycle in the graph?

Comment: Not all connected graphs have vertices of even degree only. For example, $K_4$.

Comment: Will this require two separate cases - one Eulerian and one non-Eulerian?

Comment: The graph with every edge doubled does have even degree at each vertex, so it has an Eulerian cycle.

Comment: Could you please explain what it means to "double" each edge?

Comment: It means you form the graph with the same set of vertices, but for each edge in the original graph you put in two edges in the new graph, connecting the same pair of vertices.

Comment: I suppose you could use two cases, but the Eulerian case would be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

@Daniel Schepler gives an excellent answer in the comment above. Here is a constructive proof.

If a graph is connected it contains a spanning tree. On that spanning tree, you can find a walk that visits each edge exactly twice: draw the spanning tree as a planar graph and walk around it always keeping an edge on your right.

Each tree-edge is visited exactly twice.[image]

Now add the missing edges one by one. Each time you add an edge, use it to add a detour (back and forth) to the walk.

Each non-tree-edge is visited exactly twice.[image]

Comment: (+1) what you are doing is essentially a 'spanning tree' of the edges. I don't know what this is called. Also, another way of thinking about it is you split a vertex into two (each edges then goes to one vertex or the other), and repeat this until you get a tree.

Comment: Note you actually proved a stronger statement than in the question: there exists a path that walks every edge exactly twice _in opposite directions_ (which does not follow easily from the Eulerian cycle argument).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Nice observation, bof's answer also shows this. In comments he points out a result for directed graphs: if the graph is connected and each vertex has in-degree equal to out-degree, that's sufficient for an Eulerian circuit to exist. [Wikipedia claims this result is due to König](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Directed_Eulerian_graphs). Armed with that result, the Eulerian cycle argument is straightforward: I didn't know it, so was worried the Eulerian cycle guaranteed by each vertex having even degree need not re-traverse edges in opposite directions

Answer (score 2):

Proof by induction on the size (number of edges) of the (finite) connected graph $G.$

Let $G$ be a connected graph of size $m.$ Assume that every connected graph of size less than $m$ has a closed walk that traverses each edge twice. If $m=0$ then $G$ consists of a single vertex and the trivial walk does the job. Suppose $m\gt0.$ Choose an edge $uv$ of $G.$

Case 1. $G-uv$ is connected.

By the inductive hypothesis, $G-uv$ has a closed walk $W$ that traverses each edge twice. Start at $u;$ walk on $uv$ from $u$ to $v;$ follow the closed walk $W,$ beginning and ending at $v;$ walk back to $u$ on the edge $uv.$

Case 2. $G-uv$ is disconnected.

Let $H_u$ be the component of $G-uv$ containing $u,$ and let $H_v$ be the component containing $v.$ By the inductive hypothesis, $H_u$ has a walk $W_u$ that traverses each edge twie, and $H_v$ has a walk $W_v$ that traverses each edge twice. Start at $u;$ follow the walk $W_u$ from $u$ back to $u;$ walk on $uv$ from $u$ to $v;$ follow $H_v$ from $v$ back to $v;$ return to $u$ on the edge $uv.$

Comment: (+1) As a comment notes on the other answer, this also proves the stronger statement than given in the question: there is a path that walks every edge exactly twice in opposite directions

Comment: If we replace each edge with a pair of oppositely directed edges, we can use the more general theorem which says that a connected digraph with indegree = outdegree at each vertex has a Eulerian circuit.

Comment: Thanks for that. I hadn't realised that was a sufficient condition for directed graphs, [though I now see Wikipedia states this is a result of König](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Directed_Eulerian_graphs).